# Android port scanner

Tags: android

I am trying to make a port scanner on Android and I am a little stuck. I want to see if a port is open on the router/default gateway, but nothing seems to be working.  I tried using is reachable, but I feel like that may be the wrong thing.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.content.IntentFilter; 
import android.net.DhcpInfo; 
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo; 
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.widget.TextView;

public class portscan extends Activity {

String targetHost;
public int startPort = 1; //(for uses in later programming)
public int endPort = 1000;
private Intent scanIntent;
InetAddress targetAddress;
String targetHostName;
WifiManager networkd;
DhcpInfo details;
public String   gateway;
TextView GW;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     try {
    setContentView(R.layout.port);
    GW = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gateway);
    networkd = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    details = networkd.getDhcpInfo();
    String test = intToIp(details.gateway);

    gateway = "Default Gateway: "+String.valueOf(details.gateway);
    boolean isAvailable = false;

        isAvailable = InetAddress.getByName(test).isReachable(80); //trying to see if port open
        if (isAvailable == true) {
             GW.setText("port 21 is up"); 

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }


}

public String intToIp(int i) { //this converts the DHCP information (default gateway) into a readable network address

       return ( i & 0xFF)+ "." +
                ((i >> 8 ) & 0xFF) + "." +
                ((i >> 16 ) & 0xFF)+ "." +
                ((i >> 24 ) & 0xFF );
    }
```

Comment: Looking at `isReachbable(80)`, I feel the need to point out that the argument is a `timeout value`, _not a port number_. But never mind, just don't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the code below you can add a timeout.

```
try {
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(ip, port);
    socket.connect(address, TIMEOUT);
    //OPEN
    socket.close();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    //WRONG ADDRESS
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    //TIMEOUT
} catch (IOException e) {
    //CLOSED
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `isReachable`, it is not meant for port scanning (and is unreliable for anything else too, really).

For port scanning, you use [sockets](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html). Pseudo-example:

```
   for (int port = 0; port <= 9999; port++) 
   {
        try 
        {
            // Try to create the Socket on the given port.
            Socket socket = new Socket(localhost, port);

            // If we arrive here, the port is open! 
            GW.setText( GW.getText() + String.Format( "Port %d is open. Cheers!\n", port ));

            // Don't forget to close it
            socket.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // Failed to open the port. Booh.
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for this i will try and use this soon, but i must ask i tried something like this and none of the ports were open on the 192.168.0.1 (default gate way) which i know is a load of plop ? would the code you have given work in reading the default gateways ports???